# Real time Object Detection using YOLO v3-tiny unable to detect objects through webcam

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I am trying to build an object detection application using YOLO v3-tiny. The model works fine for an input image(either downloaded from the web or for a picture from my phone) but while using the webcam, it just opens the webcam window but doesn't detect any objects. I tried giving an input image taken from the laptop webcam and it doesn't detect any objects for this either, I am unable to understand where the error lies here. It also prints all the scores and the length of the boxes as 0 when taking the webcam input.

Here is the source code for the webcam model:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
net=cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3-tiny.weights','yolov3-tiny.cfg')
classes=[]
with open("coco.txt",'r') as f:
    classes= f.read().split('\n')
 
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
    height, width, _= img.shape
    blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1/255, (416,416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    
    ln = net.getLayerNames()
    ln = [ln[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    #print(ln)
    #output_layers_names= net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()
    #print(output_layers_names)
 
    #layerOutputs=net.forward(output_layers_names)
    layerOutputs=net.forward(ln)
 
 
    boxes=[]
    confidences=[]
    class_ids=[]
 
    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            
            scores = detection[5::]
            print(scores)
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                # Object detected
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)
 
                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
 
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)
 
    
    print(len(boxes))
    indexes= cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.3, 0.4)
 
    if len(indexes) > 0:
        print(indexes.flatten())
 
 
    font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    colors=np.random.uniform(0,255,size=(len(boxes),3))
 
    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label=str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence=str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color=colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
            cv2.putText(img,label+" "+confidence,(x,y+20),font,2,(255,255,255),2)
 
 
    cv2.imshow("Image",cv2.resize(img, (800,600)))
    key= cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==27:
        break
 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone figure out where the error lies?

this is the webcam input image that doesn't work:
[image: this is the webcam input image that doesn't work]

this is the downloaded image that works:
[image: this is the downloaded image that works]

Comment: please show an image that works and one that doesn't work. no screenshots, _the actual images_ please.

Comment: sure, I've added the pictures at the end of the question, please check.

Comment: to use a technical term, that picture was taken with a "potato". the picture is comparably bad. -- the camera would benefit from more lighting. -- I'd guess that the network simply isn't confident in detecting anything in that picture, or in classifying the detection.

Comment: ah I see, so does that mean it would work in an environment with a better webcam quality?

Comment: I can't say for sure but my bet would be on "yes". *daylight* probably helps already. -- various other factors could disturb the network. your picture appears to be portrait-oriented (not landscape)... then `blobFromImage` applies its own resizing (so you don't need to do that beforehand), so that will affect the aspect ratio of objects in the picture. they'll be squashed. the network might not expect that. use `blobFromImage` with **crop=True** argument. that will maintain aspect ratio. the network might expect different input normalization (scaling, bias, ...). many possible causes.